# WebSocket (Atmosphere) with Per Request problems (Hibernate and Shiro) - Vaadin

Tags: hibernate, websocket, vaadin, shiro, atmosphere

The framework *[Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/)* in version 7 uses *[Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere)* to enable both push logic, and apparently also "all over" communications in the system when it is available, i.e. also on what ordinarly would be requests from the browser.

This is all good when Atmosphere doesn't get to use WebSockets (e.g. when Jetty is not configured with websocket support), and therefore must rely on long polling or similar HTTP "fake" push methods that just seems like a very long Servlet call.

However, when actual WebSocket are used, both *[Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)* and *[Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)* complains loudly.

The problem is that Servlet Filters doesn't "kick in" for WebSockets. Hibernate creates per-request connections with spring's OpenSessionInViewFilter, which also acts as transaction boundaries by committing/closing it on exit. Shiro creates WebSubject objects with an extension of AbstractShiroFilter - which even sticks the ServletRequest and ServletResponse objects into the subject - and clears the "ThreadContext" (which just is a ThreadLocal) upon exit.

Does anyone have any good ideas here? I was hoping for Atmosphere to have similar "try-finally"-like "filterChain.continue" logic, so that one could recreate this entry/exit logic described above. However, as I've seen it this far, Atmosphere doesn't have this kind of filtering available.

I would love to hear suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to replace servlet API filters by [Atmosfere's interceptors](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-AtmosphereInterceptor)? I suppose that they can be useful in your case.

Comment: I had actually already looked at these, but concluded that they couldn't be used. However, given your suggestion I read over again, and maybe they actually are applicable?

Answer (score 1):

Probably already solved this, but I thought I'd chime in.  Ran into the same issue using Vaadin, Spring, Hibernate stack.

Add this to your UI to turn off WebSockets and it will go through the other filters.
@Push(value=PushMode.MANUAL, transport = Transport.STREAMING)

Now I'm having an issue with the session getting wiped out.

Comment: It's not a solution, it's a workaround. Similar problem with JASS  [Push request not preserv JAAS subject on Websocket](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/16571).